# Duda Java calculador día siguiente

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar un programa para calcular el día siguiente a cualquier día, pero no consigo calcularlo para los años bisiestos por algún motivo. Utilicé las varibles `multcuatro` y `multcien` para discernir cuales serían los bisiestos, puesto que los años bisiestos son múltiplos de cuatro pero no de 100. No consigo que el programa reconozca el día extra en febrero. gracias de antemano por el apoyo

```
public class e324 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int anio;
        int numDias =0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el año.");
        anio = teclado.nextInt();
        
        boolean anioMal = (anio <= 46);
       // el formato de dia/mes/año se empezó a usar en el 46 A.C
        System.out.println("Introduce el mes");
        mes= teclado.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce el día");
        dia = teclado.nextInt();
        
        boolean mesMal = (mes >= 12 && mes <= 1);
        
        
        //formula para años bisiestos
        float mulCuatro = anio%4;
        float mulCien = anio%100;
        boolean anioBi = (mulCuatro == 0) && (mulCien !=0); 
        
        if (mulCuatro == 0 && mulCien != 0) 
        switch (mes){ 
            case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 -> numDias = 31;
            case 2 -> numDias = 29;
            case 4, 6, 9, 11 -> numDias = 30;
        }
        else { switch (mes){
            case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 -> numDias = 31;
            case 2 -> numDias = 28;
            case 4,6,9,11 ->  numDias = 30;
        }
            
      
        boolean diaMal = (numDias < dia && dia < 1);
        if  (anioMal || mesMal || diaMal) System.out.println("Formato de año incorrecto");
        else System.out.println("Formato de día correcto.");
        
        if (mes == 12 && dia == 31) System.out.println("1/1/" + (anio+1)); // fin de año
        else if ((mes == 2)& dia == numDias) System.out.println("1/" +(mes+1) + "/" + anio);  //febrero
        else System.out.println((dia+1)+ "/" + (mes) + "/" + (anio));

    }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro/a que estás cerrando bien el `}` del `switch(mes)` del `else`?

Comment: Desde la versión 8 Java incluye una API para trabajar con fechas y horas. [Revisa este post](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-time-package-y-clases-fundamentales/), no tienes por qué reinventar la rueda. Si no tienes Java 8+ puedes usar `Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron, creo que era una llave mal cerrada, siempre intenta identar el código y colocar sangrías cuando un bloque se encuentre dentro del otro para que sea mas legible para vos y los demas

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
    int numDias =0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce el año.");
    anio = teclado.nextInt();
    
    boolean anioMal = (anio <= 46);
   // el formato de dia/mes/año se empezó a usar en el 46 A.C
    System.out.println("Introduce el mes");
    mes= teclado.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el día");
    dia = teclado.nextInt();
    
    boolean mesMal = (mes >= 12 && mes <= 1);
    
    
    //formula para años bisiestos
    float mulCuatro = anio%4;
    float mulCien = anio%100;
    boolean anioBi = (mulCuatro == 0) && (mulCien !=0); 
    System.out.println(anioBi);
    
    if (anioBi) {
      switch (mes){ 
          case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:  
          numDias = 31;
          break;
          case 2: 
          numDias = 29;
          break;
          case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
          numDias = 30;
          break;
        }
    }
    else { 
      switch (mes){
        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
        numDias = 31;
        break;
        case 2: 
        numDias = 28;
        break;
        case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
        numDias = 30;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    boolean diaMal = (numDias < dia && dia < 1);
    if  (anioMal || mesMal || diaMal) System.out.println("Formato de año incorrecto");
    else System.out.println("Formato de día correcto.");
    
    System.out.println(numDias + " " + dia + " " + mes);

    if (mes == 12 && dia == 31) System.out.println("1/1/" + (anio+1)); // fin de año
    else if ((mes == 2)& dia == numDias) System.out.println("1/" +(mes+1) + "/" + anio);  //febrero
    else System.out.println((dia+1)+ "/" + (mes) + "/" + (anio));
    teclado.close();
  }
}
```